# how to execute cmd command from unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a particular command in script and execute it directly in cmd from unity for example here I am writing a simple change directory command but it is not executing directly rather I have write on my own the sample code is below

```
string pathToExe = Application.dataPath.Replace(@"/", @"\") + "\\Plugins";
    string command = "D:";
    Process process = Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGMaa.png)

Comment: If you're replacing `/` characters with ```\``` characters, but appending a string beginning with ```\\```, should you not be replacing `/` with ```\\``` too?

Comment: This will not change the current directory for your process.  It launch cmd.exe as a child process, execute the cd command you specify, but that will only change the CWD for that instance of cmd.exe, not your parent process. You do not need to replace forward slashes with backslashes, just make sure the path strings passed to cmd.exe are properly quoted.